# Configuring Spring Batch jobs via database instead of xml

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

i am new to spring batch,i need few clarifications regarding spring batch admin.
can i do job configuration related information in database instead of uploading XML file based configuration???

Comment: What would you want to come out of the database?  The XML file or something else?

Comment: yes i want to load xml file or configuration from database